# RxJS: Update An Observable From Multiple Streams

Tags: angular, rxjs6

This seems like it should be a fairly common pattern, so I'm hoping someone can help.

I'm trying to expose an Observable of "Things" via an Angular service.  My service will need to first fetch the list of Things, then listen for new Things added.  So I have two different service requests to make, but I'm trying to wrap them both up in a single Things observable so that the consuming component doesn't have to worry about the internals.

So, it looks something like this:

```
export class MyService {

  constructor(private commService: CommService){}

  get things(): Observable<Things[]> {

    // how can I get the initial list of things, then listen for updates?

    //THIS DOESN'T WORK
    return merge(commService.getAllInitialThings(), commService.listenToThingAdded());
  }

}

export class CommService{

  getAllInitialThings(): Observable<Things[]> { //etc }

  listenToThingAdded(): Observable<Thing> { //etc  }
 }
```

I've made some attempts at using concat and merge, but I dont know how to

1. Ensure that getThings() completes first
2. Update the things property, since it's an observable

Note that the listenToThingAdded may never occur, but I would still need to return the initial list of Things.

Comment: So `things` could be `merge(getThings(), listenToThingAdded())` except you want to make sure that `getThings` _completes_ before `listenToThingAdded` emits anything?

Comment: Yes, I think concat() will allow you to enforce some order (execute getAllInitialThings before listenToThingAdded), but how do I get the one Thing into the list of Things?

Answer (score 0):

What you could use is a `BehaviorSubject` than you don't need to merge or combine or anything like that:

```
private things$: BehaviorSubject<Things[]>

getThings(): Observable<Things[]> {
   if (!this.things$) {
      const things = this.getThingsFormRequest(..);
      this.things$ = new BehaviorSubject(things);

   }
   return this.things$;
}

addThing(thing: Things): void {
   const updatedThings= this.things$.value;
   updatedThings.push(thing);
   this.things$.next(updatedThings)
}
```

Using this approach the `Observalbe` returned form `getThings` will be updated as soon as a new value has been added to the array (note: the code is written by hand therefore I can't guarantee for the syntax)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I may have confused the matter with my example.  I've tried to update it to explain.  I have no control over how Things get added, I'm only responding to it, and trying to update the UI when things change.  I like your use of the BehaviorSubject, but I'm not sure how I can do this, since what is returned from my getThings is an Observable already.

Comment: ok than I dont think that this approach works for what you are trying to achive